# Eclipse Error: "Java started but returned exit code = 13"

Tags: java, windows, eclipse

On my 64 bit windows 10 operating system, I have installed 64 bit jdk1.7.

I have set up the user variable as PATH with value C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin.

After setting up environment variables, I have executed javac through command prompt.

When I try to run 64 bit eclipse, it returns the error "Java started but returned exit code = 13". Please help me figure out the problem.

Comment: I had the same problem that eclipse wouldn't start after changing variables and after computer restart everything worked. Maybe it reloads env variables, i don't know.

Comment: @Aqua I agree with Klimuik..you can try it..same happened in my case

Comment: `java -version` is executed with the `java` executable that is found in a path of the `PATH` variable. Eclipse has its own compiler, so `javac` is not required at all (the JDK is for having the source code).

Comment: @KlimiukS, I have restarted my computer but no help. In my case it is not letting me install eclipse. Btw I am trying to install 64 bit eclipse as my jdk is also 64 bit but it returns the error "Java was started but returned exit code = 13"

Comment: Just deinstall all 32 bit Java version - you don't need them anymore unless you want to load Java applets in the IE or use Eclipse 32bit edition.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the path `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin\javaw.exe` to eclipse.ini between `-vm` and `-vmargs` solved the problem.

Thanks for all the responses.

Answer (score 1):

In my case there were two copies of Java installed - one in Program Files and another in Program Files (x86). I deleted one. Then it started working.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue after I installed Eclipse.

I followed below steps:

1. Remove Java folder from "C:\Program Files (x86)\" which only contained JRE folder inside
2. Go to Control Panel -> Installed Programs
3. You might have two application.
   a) JDK version
   b) Java Update
4. Uninstall the one having keywords "Java Update"

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think 64 bit Java 8 should be pre-installed under `C:\Program Files\Java`. So your Java 8 may be 32 bit.

If you can uninstall Java 8, uninstall it. If not, check Java Configuration and in the tab "Java", tick the version 7 and untick 8.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I could solve the problem without uninstalling java 8. I have added my answer and modified the question as well to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: Sounds like your Java 8 is 32-bit.  You may want to change that.